# Commit encoding change

Tags: git, encoding

I have some files with `us-ascii` encoding committed to repository. When I change encoding to `utf-8` I cannot commit, because I get:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

How can I commit such changes?

Answer (score 4):

The 6 year old comment from @reactormonk worked for me.  I put a comment in the file, where the comment had a UTF-8 character.  Committing that change set the file encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

`us-ascii` and `utf-8` are the same in the lower 7 bits (0-127), aka all of the English characters. So there is no difference.

Comment: ... and `us-ascii` does not allow characters 128 and higher to be present at all, so it is a strict subset of `utf-8`.

Comment: It still does not answer the question. File has different encoding than I want it to have. It does not matter for me that two encodings have no difference.

Comment: Welcome to the hell of encoding. There is no encoding information inside files. You have to make an educated guess. If you want to force utf-8, add an utf-8 char.